# Default initialisation as octal || int a = 0 -> Octal

Tags: java

I wonder, why java has set the syntax for octals with a 0 before the number.

Means:

```
int a = 011;
System.out.println("Output: " + a);    //Output: 9
```

Because of this, it is logical, that this has to be handled as an octal too:

```
int b = 0;
System.out.println("Output: " + b);    //Output: 0
```

Why does java work like this? The default initialisation for int is 0. This means, it's always calculated as octal by the system and not as a binary-value. Or am I one a false way?

Comment: Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1.

Comment: Thanks you all. I didn't though about the possibility of 00. :)

Comment: If you think about what the difference would be in interpreting 0 as octal or deciaml or binary or whatever, you have answered your question.

Comment: Regarding why Java uses the preceding 0, I read a pretty convincing answer on here that basically was "that's how C did it, and that's how B did it" though I can't find the answer now.

Comment: @Radiodef [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224132/why-do-so-many-languages-treat-numbers-starting-with-0-as-octal) maybe.

Comment: @assylias That's the one! Thanks. Though my memory was wrong that it mentioned B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example the `0` is decimal not octal (not that both are not equal).

Here is an octal `0`.

```
int b = 00;
System.out.println("Output: " + b);    // Output: 0
```

Comment: Ah... this seems to make sense. :) Thank you

Answer (score 5):

No, in your second example 0 is a decimal - cf the [JLS #3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1-500):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by ***one or more*** of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

So `0` in octal would be represented as `int a = 00;`.